# How to create buttons on RPC using the C++ game sdk?

Tags: c++, discord

How to add buttons to the rich presence? I couldn't find any example in the files that come with the games-sdk

This is what I have atm:

```cpp
struct DiscordState
{
   discord::User currentUser;
   std::unique_ptr<discord::Core> core;
};

DiscordState state{};
discord::Core* core;
auto result = discord::Core::Create(..., DiscordCreateFlags_Default, &core);

state.core.reset(core);
if (state.core)
{
   state.core->SetLogHook(discord::LogLevel::Debug, [](discord::LogLevel level, const char* message) {
       qDebug() << "Log(" << static_cast<uint32_t>(level) << "): " << message << "\n";
   });

   core->UserManager().OnCurrentUserUpdate.Connect([&state]() 
   {
       state.core->UserManager().GetCurrentUser(&state.currentUser);
       qDebug() << "Current user updated: " << state.currentUser.GetUsername() << state.currentUser.GetDiscriminator() << "\n";
   });

   discord::Activity activity{};
   activity.SetType(discord::ActivityType::Playing);
   activity.SetState("Playing my game 123");
   activity.SetDetails("In a match");
   
   activity.GetAssets().SetLargeImage("..."); // The key for a large image asset from Discord Developer Portal
   activity.GetAssets().SetLargeText("...");  // The text displayed when hovering over the large image asset
   activity.GetAssets().SetSmallImage("...");
   activity.GetAssets().SetSmallText("....");
   
   core->ActivityManager().UpdateActivity(activity, [](discord::Result result) 
   {
       if (result == discord::Result::Ok)
           qDebug() << "Successfully updated activity.";
       else
           qDebug() <<  "Failed to update activity.";
   });
}
else
   qDebug() << "Failed to instantiate discord core! (err " << static_cast<int>(result) << ")\n";

QTimer coreTimer;
coreTimer.start(1000);
QObject::connect(&coreTimer, &QTimer::timeout, &a, [&]{ core->RunCallbacks(); });
```

I'm asking for buttons like these:

[image]

Are these buttons not available in the games-sdk?

I have found only examples that guide how to add these buttons to a private profile and not for a specific application.